# javascript code for removing last item from string if it exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a code which is avaliable in the following fiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/wbagktuw/**

code is like this

```
<a data-rel="http://mydomain.domian.com?z_9.asp&rpttype=298&sotBy=2sortOrder=1&pagenum=2">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var urlval = $("a").attr('data-rel');
    alert(urlval);
});
```

i am trying to remove the &pagenum=2 from the url if it exists, if it does not exists, then no problem, if exists, i want to remove that

what should i try here

Comment: I assume the page number's not always 2?

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression to replace `&pagenum=` followed by any number of digits.

Also check for the case where `pagenum` is the first parameter, in which case it follows a question mark instead of an ampersand:

```
var urlval = $('a').attr('data-rel').replace(/[\?&]pagenum=\d*/g, '');
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution without involving any 3rd party library to parse the URL

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var urlval = $("a").attr('data-rel');
    if(urlval.indexOf("pagenum")>-1){

     urlval=urlval.slice(0,urlval.lastIndexOf("&"));
    console.log(urlval);

    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wbagktuw/2/

Answer (score 0):

How about this,
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbagktuw/5/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var urlval = $("a").attr('data-rel');
    var length = urlval.length
    var start = urlval.indexOf("&pagenum=");

    if (start !== -1){
        var next = urlval.indexOf("&",start+1);
        next = (next !== -1)?next:length;
        var res = urlval.substring(start, next);
        urlval = urlval.replace(res, '');
    }
    alert(urlval);
});
```

Comment: What if `pagenum=2` is not the last param? and it's before `rpttype` for example?

Comment: Edited to account for that

Comment: Edited incase there are params with practicaly the same name

Answer (score 0):

Or even better, why not just use what JS already has built-in..

```
urlval = urlval.replace('&pagenum=2', '');
```

This will handle both the cases where `&pagenum=2` is present and not

Comment: what if `&pagenum=3` ?

Comment: In that case you can use **regex**. I didn't know that might change. You could write a regex query that checks for if **&pagenum=** followed by a number exists